# EC2 Instance - Sending STDOUT logs to Cloud Watch

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-cloudwatch

Reading the 12factor app in the [logging chapter](https://12factor.net/logs), it suggests that the application logs should be sent to STDOUT.

I found plenty of documentation on how to get the logs from STDOUT and send it to Cloud Watch when I'm running the application **in a container**.

**But, is it possible (or even recommended) to do the same when running the application in an EC2 instance (no container/docker involved)?**

The way that I managed to have my logs sent to Cloud Watch was doing what I would assume to be the standard way:

- Configure my logback-spring.xml to log to a file (Java application)
- Install the Cloud Watch agent on the instance and configure it to monitor the file above.
- Happy life, all works.

I found [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=240401) on the AWS forum where it's suggested to create a symbolic link from stdout to a file, and I would assume that this file would have to be monitored by the agent. The benefit that I can see on this approach would be that who is developing the application don't need to worry about log config, just send to stdout and who is deploying the application could configure the way it wants using some script at the startup.
But as a drawback, I can't see a way to have the application's log sent to differents streams and/or groups.

Thank you.

Comment: I really would also be interested in an answer. I mean, logging to "stdout" is widely accepted as best practice - why does the CloudWatch agent not support that out of the box?